# Mysql / Laravel: Search keywords by multi languages but only get the results of current language

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

"language" table

```
id | name    | code
-------------------
1  | English | en
2  | German  | de
```

"article" table

```
id | is_active
--------------
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

"article_translation" table

```
article_id | language_id | title
-------------------------------------------
1          | 1           | foo
1          | 2           | title1 in German
2          | 1           | title2 in English
2          | 2           | foo
```

Suppose I search "`foo`" with like condition, and I want to get the results with `language_id = 1` but still need to search the title on other languages. The following results as I expected:

```
article_id | language_id | title
-------------------------------------------
1          | 1           | foo
2          | 1           | title2 in English
```

In laravel, I tried to use group by function but the results can't make sure that the `language_id` is `1`. Also, it need to set the strict mode to false.

```
\App\ArticleTranslation::where('title', 'like', '%foo%')->groupBy('article_id')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT at1.*
FROM article_translation at1
JOIN article_translation at2 ON at1.article_id = at2.article_id 
WHERE at2.title = @title
  AND at1.language_id = @language_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72dcff4a240c83d280baa2380a47e6bf)

PS. Convert to Laravel by yourself...

Comment: Thanks! It's works. But sorry for can't vote to you since I am new account.

Comment: @SteveKwok You may mark the answer as accepted one (check mark to the left of the answer text).

Answer (score 0):

Add relations for easy queries

```
// Language model
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}

// Article model
public function languages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class);
}

// in controller
$articles = Language::find(1)->articles()->wherePivot('title', 'like', '%foo%')->get();
foreach($articles as $article){
    dump($article); // $title = $article->pivot->title
}
```